# Cost function for Minimizing cost of a hole

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]

I'm solving a problem where I have to minimize the cost of a hole. *The depth $d$ needs to be 4 times the width $b$ of the hole*. What should my cost function be?
This i what I have come up with:

Cost = $4d*b + 4d*b + 4d*b + 4d*b + b*b = 16db+b^2$

Volume = $b*b*d = b^2d$

Am i on the right track?
Thanks

Comment: I think more details are needed; I mean, if cost is related to the hole being dug out from the ground, the cost should be proportional to the volume since it's proportional to the weight of all that has the be removed to create said hole (assuming uniform density). However, you can also add a term proportional to depth if it's harder to scoop out material the deeper you go... Of course, the cost may not be related to digging at all.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that the inside of the hole will be covered with an expensive material.

Comment: Why does the depth have to be four times the width? Is that something you computed or is that an additional constraint from a part of the text we are not shown?

Comment: Yes it is an additional constraint from a part of the text we are not shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d=4b$ and $b^2d=100000$, then we can solve a set of simultaneous equations to find our solution. $b^2(4b)=100000 \rightarrow 4b^3=100000 \rightarrow b^3=25000 \rightarrow b\approx 29.2401773821m$. This means that $d=4(29.2401773821)\approx 116.960709529m$. There are no other solutions, so this is the optimal (and only) choice to make.

*If, however, $d\neq 4b$, we can still solve.*
First, relate $b$ and $d$ in terms of each other. As $100,000=b^2d$, therefore, $d=\dfrac{100,000}{b^2}$. Plugging this in to the first equation gives us $C=16(\dfrac{100,000}{b^2})b+b^2 \rightarrow C=b^2+\dfrac{1,600,000}{b}$
To solve for the minimum cost, we can find the vertex of the created function, which occurs where $b \approx 92.8$. This means that the cheapest cost for the hole would be a hole with dimensions $92.8m*92.8m*11.6m$

Comment: Thank you for the answer @PiGuy314, but the depth should be 4 times the width of the hole

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice until after I posted my answer. I updated it, though. : )

Comment: Thanks again @ PiGuy314. So the solution doesn't involve differentiation?

Comment: Not with the rule set you gave, I don't believe. You would only need it to calculate the vertex of the curve if d wasn't 4b, but math graphing utilities will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your function for volume is correct. This is something you can use to compute the values for the length or depth with respect to the other variable since you already know the value for V.

Also, you know that $d = 4b$ per the last constraint. This reduces the problem down to a single variable optimization problem.

You function for cost is not correct; You want to minimize area while keeping volume constant.